# Como eu descrevo uma equação da reta de um glmm em um gráfico xy no R?

Tags: r, gráfico

Olá, 
tenho dados de idade (X) e riqueza de espécies por amostra (y). Fiz um glmm e gostaria de saber como escrever a equação de forma correta na figura no R. Alguém tem algum site/paper para indicar?

Obg,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Existem várias formas de incluir a equação na figura, a depender de como você está plotando o gráfico. Aqui seguem alguns exemplos, caso queira uma resposta mais específica para o seu problema, favor inserir o código que você criou.

Usando `plot`:

```
x<- runif(1000, min = 0, max=5)
y<- pi + x^2
plot(x, y, main= expression(Gráfico ~ da ~ Equação ~ pi + x^2))
```

Gera a figura: [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Usando `ggplot`:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpmisc)
dados <- data.frame(x = c(1:100))
dados$y <- pi + dados$x^2 + rnorm(100, sd = 500)
minha.formula <- y ~ x
ggplot(data = dados, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_point()+
  geom_smooth(method = "glm", se=FALSE, color="blue", formula = minha.formula) +
  stat_poly_eq(formula = minha.formula,
               eq.with.lhs = "italic(hat(y))~`=`~",
               aes(label = paste(..eq.label.., ..rr.label.., ..AIC.label.., sep =  "*plain(\",\")~")), 
               parse = TRUE) +
  labs(title= expression(Gráfico ~ da ~ Equação: ~ pi +x^2))
```

Gera a figura:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Espero ter ajudado :)

Comment: Oi Marina. Muito boa a sua dica.

Comment: olá, gostei muito dessa solução, porém gostaria de saber se tem como colocar as significâncias dos coeficientes, tentei localizar de onde a função `stat_poly_eq`, retira `..eq.label..` porém não tive êxito, você saberia se tem como colocar?

Comment: Olá @JeanKarlos, `stat_poly_eq` computa `x`, `y`, `eq.label`, `rr.label`, `adj.rr.label`, `AIC.label` e `BIC.label` (veja a [documentação](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggpmisc/ggpmisc.pdf)). Existem outras formas de colocar fórmula e outras informações no gráfico. [Esse post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7549694/adding-regression-line-equation-and-r2-on-graph) no SO em inglês tem um exemplo com a inclusão do p-valor.